# Oracle sort data with 3 columns conditions

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to sort my data on `Oracle` with 3 columns conditions.

Need to `ORDER BY` DATEADDED, ARTICLEID_FK, BOX_SERIAL_NO

What I've to do so far on my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    S.FORM_NO,
    S.ARTICLEID_FK,
    S.BOX_SERIAL_NO,
    S.ACTUAL_WEIGHT,
    TO_CHAR(S.DATEADDED, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS DATEADDEDS,
    S.ADDEDBY,
    B.BOX_SERIAL_NO,
    B.ARTICLEID_FK,
    B.DATE_CODE
FROM 
    WA_LA_TBL_ARTICLES_SCAN S JOIN WA_LA_TBL_ARTICLES_BOX_SN B ON 
        S.BOX_SERIAL_NO = B.BOX_SERIAL_NO 
        AND TO_CHAR(S.DATEADDED, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') BETWEEN 
              '2018-01-15 08:00' AND '2018-01-16 07:59'
ORDER BY S.ARTICLEID_FK ASC, B.BOX_SERIAL_NO ASC, S.DATEADDED DESC
```

When I run that query, I got this error:

```
ORA-01791: not a SELECTed expression
```

The error is pointing to `S.DATEADDED DESC`

The logic is, first need to sort by Date then Article ID then Box Serial No.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a `select distinct` query, you can only order by the columns being selected.  So, one simple solution is to select the column.  Alternatively, use `group by`:

```
SELECT S.FORM_NO, S.ARTICLEID_FK, S.BOX_SERIAL_NO, S.ACTUAL_WEIGHT,
       TO_CHAR(S.DATEADDED, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS DATEADDEDS,
       S.ADDEDBY, B.BOX_SERIAL_NO, B.ARTICLEID_FK, B.DATE_CODE
FROM WA_LA_TBL_ARTICLES_SCAN S JOIN
     WA_LA_TBL_ARTICLES_BOX_SN B
     ON S.BOX_SERIAL_NO = B.BOX_SERIAL_NO AND
        S.DATEADDED BETWEEN TIMESTAMP '2018-01-15 08:00:00' AND TIMESTAMP '2018-01-16 07:59:00'
GROUP BY S.FORM_NO, S.ARTICLEID_FK, S.BOX_SERIAL_NO, S.ACTUAL_WEIGHT,
         TO_CHAR(S.DATEADDED, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),
         S.ADDEDBY, B.BOX_SERIAL_NO, B.ARTICLEID_FK, B.DATE_CODE
ORDER BY S.ARTICLEID_FK ASC, B.BOX_SERIAL_NO ASC,
         MAX(S.DATEADDED) DESC;
```

Notes:

- The date comparison now uses only date arithmetic.  No need to convert to strings for date comparisons.
- The `ORDER BY` uses `MAX()`.  That should be fine for your purposes.
- You do not want to `ORDER BY` the string version.  The format is wrong, because the day is first (and strings are sorted as strings, not dates).

Comment: Hi... just now tested it and got error: ORA-01861: literal does not match format string

Comment: @HiDayurieDave . . . When you have a time component, the keyword is `TIMESTAMP` rather than `DATE`.

Comment: Just now tried your edited code and got error: ORA-01861: literal does not match format string

Answer (score 1):

From [Oracle9i Database Error Messages](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96525/e1500.htm#1003914):

> **ORA-01791 not a SELECTed expression**
>
> **Cause:** There is an incorrect ORDER BY item. The query is a SELECT DISTINCT query with an ORDER BY clause. In this context, all ORDER BY items must be constants, SELECT list expressions, or expressions whose operands are constants or SELECT list expressions.
>
> **Action:** Remove the inappropriate ORDER BY item from the SELECT list and retry the statement.

This select-distinct-query is equivalent to the following group-by-query

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    S.FORM_NO,
    S.ARTICLEID_FK,
    S.BOX_SERIAL_NO,
    S.ACTUAL_WEIGHT,
    TO_CHAR(S.DATEADDED, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS DATEADDEDS,
    S.ADDEDBY,
    B.BOX_SERIAL_NO,
    B.ARTICLEID_FK,
    B.DATE_CODE
FROM 
    WA_LA_TBL_ARTICLES_SCAN S JOIN WA_LA_TBL_ARTICLES_BOX_SN B ON 
        S.BOX_SERIAL_NO = B.BOX_SERIAL_NO 
        AND TO_CHAR(S.DATEADDED, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') BETWEEN 
              '2018-01-15 08:00' AND '2018-01-16 07:59'
ORDER BY S.ARTICLEID_FK ASC, B.BOX_SERIAL_NO ASC, S.DATEADDED DESC
```

This select-distinct-query is equivalent to the following group-by-query:

```
SELECT 
    S.FORM_NO,
    S.ARTICLEID_FK,
    S.BOX_SERIAL_NO,
    S.ACTUAL_WEIGHT,
    TO_CHAR(S.DATEADDED, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS DATEADDEDS,
    S.ADDEDBY,
    B.BOX_SERIAL_NO,
    B.ARTICLEID_FK,
    B.DATE_CODE
FROM 
    WA_LA_TBL_ARTICLES_SCAN S JOIN WA_LA_TBL_ARTICLES_BOX_SN B ON 
        S.BOX_SERIAL_NO = B.BOX_SERIAL_NO 
        AND TO_CHAR(S.DATEADDED, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') BETWEEN 
              '2018-01-15 08:00' AND '2018-01-16 07:59'
GROUP BY
    S.FORM_NO,
    S.ARTICLEID_FK,
    S.BOX_SERIAL_NO,
    S.ACTUAL_WEIGHT,
    TO_CHAR(S.DATEADDED, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS DATEADDEDS,
    S.ADDEDBY,
    B.BOX_SERIAL_NO,
    B.ARTICLEID_FK,
    B.DATE_CODE
ORDER BY S.ARTICLEID_FK ASC, B.BOX_SERIAL_NO ASC, S.DATEADDED DESC
```

Now it is clear that Oracle has to raise such an error: the members of a group of data have all the same `TO_CHAR(S.DATEADDED,...)`
but that does not gurantee the same  `S.DATEADDED` values. Actually the format sting 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' does gurantee this but Oracle does not make such a deep analysis. If a function is used, oracle assumes tha different argument can result in the same funtion values.

So you can avoid the error by change the query to the following one

```
SELECT 
    S.FORM_NO,
    S.ARTICLEID_FK,
    S.BOX_SERIAL_NO,
    S.ACTUAL_WEIGHT,
    TO_CHAR(S.DATEADDED, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS DATEADDEDS,
    S.ADDEDBY,
    B.BOX_SERIAL_NO,
    B.ARTICLEID_FK,
    B.DATE_CODE
FROM 
    WA_LA_TBL_ARTICLES_SCAN S JOIN WA_LA_TBL_ARTICLES_BOX_SN B ON 
        S.BOX_SERIAL_NO = B.BOX_SERIAL_NO 
        AND TO_CHAR(S.DATEADDED, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') BETWEEN 
              '2018-01-15 08:00' AND '2018-01-16 07:59'
GROUP BY
    S.FORM_NO,
    S.ARTICLEID_FK,
    S.BOX_SERIAL_NO,
    S.ACTUAL_WEIGHT,
    S.DATEADDED,
    S.ADDEDBY,
    B.BOX_SERIAL_NO,
    B.ARTICLEID_FK,
    B.DATE_CODE
ORDER BY S.ARTICLEID_FK ASC, B.BOX_SERIAL_NO ASC, S.DATEADDED DESC
```

But note tha there are some things that are strange

You say that you sort 'by Date then Article ID then Box Serial No'. That is not true, you sort by Article ID then Box Serial No and then Date,

`TO_CHAR(S.DATEADDED, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') BETWEEN '2018-01-15 08:00' AND '2018-01-16 07:59'` is not optimal. Applying a function to a column value may prevent the usage of an index. So you should rewrite this clause to

```
 S.DATEADDED between TO_DATE('2018-01-15 08:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') and TO_DATE('2018-01-16 07:59:59','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```